# Prevent UIScrollView scroll horizontally if auto layout is on

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have this scrollview with autolayout. Scroll view has the blue color. In **landscape** mode it looks good.

[image]

But in **portrait** mode instead of let horizontally scroll I would reduce the width of the view with orange color to keep 20px distance from right edge too.

How? I set up 20px constrain on right side also, but the **contentSize not get updated** when rotating. I know that I am not allowed to set contentSize programmatically in case of autolayout.

[image]

Here you can see the constrains I set up:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. Instead of setting the right constrains, I created constrain for the width of view, created an IBOutlet for the constrain, and in code I set the constant of the constrain.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {

        //self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(944, 1600);
        _viewWidthConstrain.constant = 944;

    } else {

        //self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 1600);
        _viewWidthConstrain.constant = 500;
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]